# Is it possible to manually update the value of a Behaviour? (Functional Reactive Programming, Threepenny)

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

I really hope I haven't gone down a dead-end here. I have a Behaviour that gives the currently selected Color, and the current mouse coordinates, then carries out a task when the mouse is clicked. That task involves looking at a list and then updating the values in that list, for it to be retrieved later. The fact that I can "store" the selected color gives me hope that storing a list can be done in a similar manner. I'm just at a dead end and not sure how to solve this. Would really appreciate some help.

```
-- There is a Blue button and a Red button on our UI. Whichever
-- button was clicked last is our current color selection.
colorRedSelected = const ColorRed <$ UI.click redButton
colorBlueSelected = const ColorBlue <$ UI.click blueButton

-- we combine both the above Events to create a new one that tells us the current selected color
colorSelected = unionWith const colorRedSelected colorBlueSelected

-- accumulate values for our Behaviour, starting with ColorRed selected by default
colorMode       <- accumB ColorRed modeEvent

-- create a Behaviour
mouseCoordinate   <- stepper (0,0) $ UI.mousemove canvas

-- want to start with the list [1,2,3,4], but this value should change later.
-- I have 'never' here, as I don't know what else to put here yet.

listState      <- accumB ([1,2,3,4]) never

-- Combine the Behaviours, we now have a tuple (chosenColorMode, mouseCoordinateTuple, savedList)

let choices = (,,) <$> colorMode <*> mouseCoordinate <*> listState

-- Apply the event (of the user clicking the canvas) to the Behaviour,
-- creating a new Event that returns the above tuple when it fires    

makeChoice = choices <@ UI.click canvas

onEvent makeChoice $ \(colorMode, (x,y), savedList) -> do    
    ...
    -- in this block we use the savedList, and generate a newList.
    -- I want to update the choicePosition behaviour so that the newList
    -- replaces the old savedList.
```

Comment: I can't write a full answer right now, but here's the gist of it: the general principle is that we don't manually update values of behaviors, but rather specify how they will change when defining them. In your case, if `listState` is a `Behavior [Integer]`, that means you want to replace `never` with an `Event ([Integer] -> [Integer])` built from `UI.click canvas` (in a similar way to `makeChoice`), with the function carried by this event specifying how the list should change.

Comment: I've made some great progress on this, thanks to your suggestion. Thank you! I'll post my new approach as soon as I get some free time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full credit to [this response from duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691558/is-it-possible-to-manually-update-the-value-of-a-behaviour-functional-reactive?noredirect=1#comment124978753_70691558), I'll just go through how it was solved:

Let's say we have a function that modifies a list somehow, depending on some value. How/why `updateMyList` modifies the list doesn't really matter for this explanation, we just need to know its type. For this example, we'll say the value that determines how the list changes is a mouse coordinate tuple (x, y), which we'll pass as its first parameter:

```hs
updateMyList :: (Double, Double) -> [Integer] -> [Integer]
updateMyList (x, y) oldList = ...
```

If we have an Event that tells us the mouse coordinates when the user clicks:

```
mouseCoords :: Behavior (Double, Double)
mouseCoords <- stepper (0,0) $ UI.mousemove canvas

mouseClicked :: Event (Double, Double)
mouseClicked = mouseCoords <@ UI.click canvas -- this is the Event we need
```

What we need to do is `fmap` the list-updating function onto `mouseClicked`:

```
listChangeEvent = fmap updateMyList mouseClicked
```

So we've created a new Event: when `mouseClicked` is triggered, the mouse coordinates are passed as the *first* parameter to `updateMyList`, and that is the value of our new Event at that timestamp. But this is a partially applied function, `updateMyList` still requires an `[Integer]` as a parameter, so as a result, `listChangeEvent` has the following type:

```
listChangeEvent :: Event ([Integer] -> [Integer])
```

Now, this is the clever part: if we use `accumB` and specify the starting accumulator (i.e. our starting list, `[1,2,3,4]`), and then also use the above `listChangeEvent` as the Event `accumB` takes its value from:

```
listState      <- accumB ([1,2,3,4]) listChangeEvent
```

Then **that accumulator** is what will be passed to the function in `Event ([Integer] -> [Integer])`. Meaning the first time the `listChangeEvent` triggers, `updateMyList` will be called with:

```
updateMyList (x, y) [1,2,3,4] -- (x, y) being the mouse coordinates at that time
```

And the result of that becomes the **new** accumulator value in `listState`, and that new list will be used as the parameter to `updateMyList` the next time `listChangeEvent`triggers, and so on.

We can use this for anything at all, it doesn't necessarily have to be a list that we're modifying. This just gives us a way to initialize a Behavior with a value, and that we can specify exactly how the next value of the Behavior is derived, by creating a function that is equivalent to `updateMyList`.

Comment: Nicely written explanation; good answer :)